# How to Copy all the .c files starting with letter [h-o] to directory h-oFiles

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to accomplish this one command and this is what I tried:

```
sudo cp /hw2/ladsrc/.c[a-g] /hw2/a-gFiles
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming a few things:

1. The title of the question is **correct**
2. The command in the question was merely an example and not what you actually typed

Here is the easiest way of copying the files (as others have pointed out):

```
cp /hw2/ladsrc/[h-o]*.c /hw2/h-oFiles
```

Here is a better way of doing the copy. There is a small chance that there are a lot of files that meet your criteria. If that is the case, xargs is a better solution. In addition, you might also have spaces or special characters in the file names. Try this instead (3 files are copied at once via the -n option, which can be faster than just a regular copy):

```
find /hw2/ladsrc/ -name "[h-o]*.c" | xargs -n 3 -I {} cp "{}" /hw2/h-oFiles
```

[Note]: I am not sure why sudo was used. The problem description didn't say. If you own the files as a regular user, there is no need to use sudo. If you don't own the files that you are trying to copy and have sudo privileges, then sudo is needed to make the copy. In that case you would want to use the -p flag with cp (copy) to perserve file ownership and file permissions. If not, the root users will take ownership of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to write

```
 sudo cp /hw2/ladsrc/[a-g]*.c /hw2/a-gFiles
```

Comment: Hastur Thanks for the reply I'm trying it out right now

Comment: I want to post as solved but where do i do that?